# Powershell nested DataTable

Tags: .net, powershell, datatable

I am trying to nest a DataTable in a Powershell script.
Consider a very simple datatable:

```
$somedt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$somedt.Columns.Add('foo')
[void]$somedt.Columns.Add('bar')
[void]$somedt.Rows.Add('boo', 'bah')
[void]$somedt.Rows.Add('typed', 'better')
$somedt.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     True     DataTable                                System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent
```

I would like to have this as a value in another datatable. So let's create one:

```
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$dt.Columns.Add('Title')

$dtcol = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn
$dtcol.ColumnName = "TableData"
$dtcol.DataType = "System.Data.DataTable"
$dtcol.DefaultValue = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

[void]$dt.Columns.Add($dtcol)
[void]$dt.Rows.Add("Orange")
[void]$dt.Rows.Add("Red")

$dt | Format-Table -AutoSize


Title  TableData
-----  ---------
Orange {}       
Red    {}
```

And we verify:

```
$dt.Columns["TableData"].DataType

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     True     DataTable                                System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent
```

And

```
$dt.Rows[1].TableData.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     True     DataTable                                System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent
```

So now I verify $somedt's type and create a new DataRow which holds $somedt as it's 'TableData' value:

```
$somedt.gettype()
$myrow = $dt.NewRow()
$myrow["Title"] = 'Blue'
$myrow["TableData"] = $somedt

$myrow

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     True     DataTable                                System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent
```

**Type of value has a mismatch with column type Couldn't store  in TableData Column.  Expected type is DataTable.
    At line:5 char:1
    + $myrow["TableData"] = $somedt
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException**

```
Title     : Blue
TableData : {}
```

So why does this fail? It seems that Powershell Takes the DataTable and converts it into a collection of DataRows. How can I prevent this from happening?

It is kind of the reverse of the "comma trick" used when returning values from a function, or so it seems.

I can remove the DataType restriction from the 'TableData' column but that just leads to default empty DataTables not added and the nested datatble is added as a collection of DataRows

```
Title  TableData                              
-----  ---------                              
Orange                                        
Red                                           
Blue   System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow
```

I would really like to be able to use some of the functionality of DataTables but I also need the nesting. If not I would need to rethink / refactor quite a bit. The documentation on DataColumn.DataType does not mention these complex types but that part of the code seems to work fine initially.

Am I doing something wrong? or is this simply not possible?

P.s. this needs to work in Powershell v3.0 / .Net 4.5

Comment: `$somedt = (New-Object System.Data.DataTable).PSObject.BaseObject`

Comment: @PetSerAl That's it !! Thanks!. Could you put it in an answer so I can mark it as such? I am reading up on this baseobject property right now but already tested and it works as expected. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception happens due to PowerShell wrap result of `New-Object` cmdlet into `PSObject` object:

```
$DataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$DataTableUnwrapped = $DataTable.PSObject.BaseObject
[Type]::GetTypeArray(($DataTable,$DataTableUnwrapped)).FullName
```

This commands will print:

```
System.Management.Automation.PSObject
System.Data.DataTable
```

In some cases PowerShell unwrap `PSObject` automatically:

```
[Object]::ReferenceEquals($DataTable,$DataTableUnwrapped) #return True
```

In other cases, like assignment to property or indexer with type `Object`:

```
$myrow["TableData"] = $somedt
$myrow.TableData = $somedt
```

unwrapping does not happens and property or indexer accessor got `PSObject` instance.

As `System.Data` API is not PowerShell aware, it does not know how to unwrap `PSObject` or convert it to `DataTable`. So that, it refuse to store `PSObject` in column typed as `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around a bit more I found that the Add() method does not mess with the datatype if I called it like this:

```
$dt.Rows.Add("Blue",$somedt) | Out-Null
```

So digging into the documentation, I completely overlooked this:
[How to: Add Rows to a DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx)

So because they are typed datacolumns they should be addressed as such, using dot notation. Trying the following unfortunately also fails:

```
$somedt.gettype()
$myrow = $dt.NewRow()
$myrow.Title = 'Blue'
$myrow.TableData = $somedt

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     True     DataTable                                System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent                                                                                                                                                         
Exception setting "TableData": "Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow> in TableData Column.  Expected type is DataTable."
At line:5 char:1
+ $myrow.TableData = $somedt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterSetValue
```

However, according to [Adding Data to a DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z16c79x4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Passing an array of values, typed as Object, to the Add method creates a new row inside the table and sets its column values to the values in the object array. Note that values in the array are matched sequentially to the columns, based on the order in which they appear in the table.

doing it like this seems to work:

```
$dt.Rows.Add('Blue', $somedt) | Out-Null

$dt | Format-Table -AutoSize

$dt.rows[2].TableData.gettype()
```

And results in:

```
Title  TableData
-----  ---------
Orange {}       
Red    {}       



Title  TableData                                 
-----  ---------                                 
Orange {}                                        
Red    {}                                        
Blue   {System.Data.DataRow, System.Data.DataRow}



IsPublic IsSerial Name      BaseType                                     
-------- -------- ----      --------                                     
True     True     DataTable System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent
```

I don't really fancy this way, as it is depending on the order of the columns. It also displays the value as being a collection of datarows which weirds me out a bit but the GetType() shows that it is indeed a DataTable.

Finally I can then do something like:

```
$rccol = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn
$rccol.ColumnName = "RowCount"
[void]$dt.Columns.Add($rccol)

foreach ($row in $dt.Rows) {
    $row.RowCount = $row.TableData.Rows.Count
}

$dt | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Which then results in:

```
Title  TableData                                  RowCount
-----  ---------                                  --------
Orange {}                                         0       
Red    {}                                         0       
Blue   {System.Data.DataRow, System.Data.DataRow} 2
```

Still I'd like to know why it fails on adding a DataTable using the NewRow() procedure so I can explicitly add the value to that column, in stead of relying on column order (which might change over time).

UPDATE from PetSerAl's suggestion, changing the instantiation of $somedt indeed works, although I don't understand why precisely. Do BaseObjects somehow evade the collection unwinding when passed in as a parameter or something like that??

Anyway, this works fine:

```
$somedt = (New-Object System.Data.DataTable).PSObject.BaseObject
[void]$somedt.Columns.add('foo')
[void]$somedt.Columns.Add('bar')
[void]$somedt.Rows.Add('boo', 'bah')
[void]$somedt.Rows.Add('typed', 'better')

$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$dt.Columns.Add('Title')

$dtcol = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn
$dtcol.ColumnName = "TableData"
$dtcol.DataType = "System.Data.DataTable"
$dtcol.DefaultValue = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

[void]$dt.Columns.Add($dtcol)
[void]$dt.Rows.Add("Orange")
[void]$dt.Rows.Add("Red")

$dt | Format-Table -AutoSize

$myrow = $dt.NewRow()
$myrow.Title = 'Blue'
$myrow.TableData = $somedt
$dt.Rows.Add($myrow)

$dt | Format-Table -AutoSize

$dt.rows[2].TableData.gettype()
```

Output:

```
Title  TableData
-----  ---------
Orange {}       
Red    {}       



Title  TableData                                 
-----  ---------                                 
Orange {}                                        
Red    {}                                        
Blue   {System.Data.DataRow, System.Data.DataRow}



IsPublic IsSerial Name      BaseType                                     
-------- -------- ----      --------                                     
True     True     DataTable System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent
```